# render animation with eevee, volumetric disappear some frames

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

i have a bug with eevee when i rendering, my volumetric ambiance disappear sometimes without any reason.
I noticed it once a sequence was rendered, some frame, totally random, i haven't my volumetric.

Look for exemple frame 187 its ok, 188 bug, i retry instant to render 188, and it's ok.

[image: render frame 187]
[image: render frame 188]
[image: render frame 188(2)]

I think it may be the fact that my object with volumetric shader have a animation, it grows until the camera is immersed in it, and finds the volume. But when this object become static, after on my animation, i have a same problem.

I can't make this volumetric on world, i have already it for ambiance of full scene. My animation it's like putting your head in water.

If somebody have tricks to avoid this, I can save time rather than render bugged frames one by one.

Thx community !

Comment: I cant fix this bug, really no solutions, but i have found how resolve my problem, using 2 world volume with a mix shader for switch from one to the other.

Comment: If it is indeed a bug then you should report it so that it gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my prob with this configuration of world shaders :

[image]

But use volumectric on object is not fixed with Eevee, i have no idea how fix this bug